# Genetic alogirthm

Tags: differential-equations

I'm having trouble approximating the natural chain curve passing through the points A(-1,2) and B(1,2) using the genetic algorithm. For some reason I don't get any errors, but the animation doesn't change for any of my iterations. I think I made some kind of error when writing the natural chain curve but I'm not seeing it.

Here is my code:

```
nitialPopulation[fitnessFunc_, {x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}, n_ : 10] :=
  Module[{partition , y, u, v},
   partition = Range[0, n - 1]/(n - 1);
   u = x0 + (x1 - x0) partition;
   v = y0 + (y1 - y0) partition;
   y = Interpolation[Transpose[{u, v}]];
   {u, v, y, fitnessFunc[y]}
   ];
Mutation[fitnessFunc_, {u_, v_, y_, fitness_}, \[CurlyEpsilon]_] :=
  Module[{n, index, dv , newv, newy},
   n = Length[u] - 1;
   index = RandomInteger[{2, n}];
   dv = RandomReal[{-\[CurlyEpsilon], \[CurlyEpsilon]}];
   newv = v;
   newv[[index]] = newv[[index]] + dv;
   newy = Interpolation[Transpose[{u, newv}]];
   {u, newv, newy, fitnessFunc[newy]}
   ];
RunLifeCycle[fitnessFunc_, population_, 
   times_ : 10, \[CurlyEpsilon]_ : 0.1] :=
  Module[{newpop, oldpop = population},
   Do[
    newpop = Mutation[fitnessFunc, oldpop, \[CurlyEpsilon]];
    If[newpop[[-1]] > oldpop[[-1]],
     oldpop = newpop;
     ];
    , times
    ];
   oldpop
   ];
cateq = Function[x, \[Lambda] + c*Cosh[x/c]];
sol = cateq /. 
   NSolve[{cateq[1] == 2, cateq[-1] == 2, \[Lambda] == 0}, {\[Lambda],
      c}, Reals];
FitnessI1[y_] := -NIntegrate[sol[[2]][x], {x, -1, 1}]
optimalFitness = FitnessI1[sol[[2]][x] /. {x -> #} &]
population = InitialPopulation[FitnessI1, {-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
iterationCount = 0;
times = 10;
Manipulate[
    If[run,
    population = RunLifeCycle[FitnessI1, population, times, 0.05];
    iterationCount = iterationCount + times;
    ];
 Column@List[
   "Iteráció:    " <> ToString[iterationCount],
   "Fitnesz:     " <> ToString[population[[-1]]],
   "Opt. Fitnes: " <> ToString[optimalFitness],
   Show[
    Plot[{sol[[2]][x], population[[3]][x]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}],
    ListPlot[Transpose[population[[1 ;; 2]]], PlotStyle -> Blue],
    ImageSize -> Medium
    ]
   ],
 "Szimuláció", {{run, False}, None}, 
 Button["Run/Stop", run = Not[run]], SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: There is something wrong in your definition for ``FitnessI1``. You make ``y`` as a function argument, but then you don't use it for calculating the fitness. That is why the result of the fitness function is always the same, and nothing changes.